# I keep getting an undefined method for a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nomethoderror

I've been searching and searching but I cannot find anything to help me with this. I am building an app that allows you to schedule a meeting in a room. The error I'm receiving is

```
undefined method 'room_id' for #<Room:0x007fa25cc51128>
```

Here is where the error is occuring in my `application.html.erb`:

```
<li><%= link_to "Schedule a Meeting", new_room_meeting_path(@user, @meeting,    @room.room_id)%></li>
```

Here is my meetings controller:

```
class MeetingsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!


def new
  @meeting = Meeting.new
  @rooms = Room.all
  @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
end



def index
  @meetings = Meeting.all
end

def show
  @meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @meeting.comments
  @room = Room.find(params[:id])

end

def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @meeting = @user.meetings.create(meeting_params)
  NotificationMailer.meeting_scheduled(@meeting).deliver_now

  if @meeting.save
    redirect_to root_path, flash: { notice: "Congratulations!!! Your meeting    has been scheduled successfully!!!"}

  else
    render :new
  end
end



private

def meeting_params
  params.require(:meeting).permit(:name, :start_time, :end_time, :user_id,   :room_id)
end


end
```

Here is my Meeting model:

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :room
has_many :comments

validates_presence_of :user_id, :room_id, :name

def meeting_author_email
  user.try(:email)
end

def self.send_reminder_text_message(body, phone)
  @account_sid = ENV['twilio_account_sid']
  @auth_token = ENV['twilio_auth_token']
  @from_phone_number = ENV['twilio_phone_number']

  @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)

  @twilio_client.account.messages.create( to: phone,
                                        from: @from_phone_number,
                                        body: body

                                      )
end

def start_timestamp
  (start_time - 6.hours).strftime('%b %e, %l:%M %p')
end

def end_timestamp
  (end_time - 6.hours).strftime('%b %e, %l:%M %p')
end
end
```

The correct URI is: `/rooms/:room_id/meetings/new(.:format)`

I don't know what the problem is and it is really frustrating me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've searched over and over and have been unable to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: You will get better responses to questions if you can narrow it down to some specific lines and to explicitly ask a question about one particular thing. As explained in the guides, [don't just copy in your entire program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I thought if I shared a little more it can give some better context. Will improve on that moving forward. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not a Rails guy, but came across this question in the review queue, and it struck me as difficult to pinpoint. Maybe the code is more meaningful to Rails developers.  But yes, in general, explicit and reproducible problems are easier to answer.  Try to edit this question once you narrow down / debug more. You'll either get to a specific spot that is answerable or you may solve it yourself! (don't forget to answer your own questions if you do!) Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Room` model doesn't have a column called `room_id`, but it does have a column called `id`. Every object in your application has an automatically generated `id` column as part of the "magic" of Rails. The `room_id` column that you seem to want belongs to the `meetings` table, but you indicated that it should come from your `room` object.

Replace the line:

```
Schedule a Meeting", new_room_meeting_path(@user, @meeting, @room.room_id)%></li>
```

with:

```
Schedule a Meeting", new_room_meeting_path(@user, @meeting, @meeting.room_id)%></li>
```

Comment: I've tried that and now I'm getting this error: No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"meetings", :format=>#<Meeting id: nil, name: nil, start_time: nil, end_time: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil, room_id: nil>, :room_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:room_id]

Comment: Thanks for replying as well! I have seeded my database so I do not know why it is saying the key is missing for :room_id

Comment: id is an implicit column for all Rails tables. You don't have to specify an id column at all because it's automatically generated (as are the created and updated timestamp columns). If you're creating a Room model and specifying room_id, you're making a mistake (unless room_id is a foreign key to a different Room object). Also, the fact that you're getting a bunch of nils means you're passing garbage data. See modified answer.

Comment: Thanks I truly appreciate your help. I've re-seeded DB and now I'm getting this error: "Couldn't find Room with 'id'=".. This error is on my 'new' method of my Meetings controller. When I ran Rails C, I see all of my data there and it is showing that I do have my id present for each of the 9 rooms I've seeded.

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated the URI is "/rooms/:room_id/meetings/new(.:format)", the first part of the fix is to use the :id attribute instead of the: room_id attribute on your @room object, and second to remove the unnecessary objects from your route. You only need the id attribute for a valid URI:

```
<li><%= "Schedule a Meeting", new_room_meeting_path(@room.id)%></li>
```

Comment: Thanks I've just tried that and now I'm getting this error "Couldn't find room with 'id'=" where I am calling the instance of a room to display a specific id.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about the room object you are loading, which route you on when having the bug, as well as more context. It seems that you are passing an incorrect (id/data type) to Room.find(params[:room_id]). You can also try: new_room_meeting_path(@room)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was calling the wrong URI.. The correct one was:

```
    <li><%= link_to "Schedule a Meeting", new_user_meeting_path(current_user) %></li>
```

Is what did the trick. I also made the mistake of not dealing with seed data properly which really threw me for a loop. So once again, THANKS again to all who helped me out. I was working on an old project so I had a lot to go over.